# How to hide password ENTIRELY in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was searching a lot on the internet about how to hide password in TextFormField, the entirely one. Because obscureText doesn't hide all of it, they give a slightly every character you typed

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL2wS.jpg)

Is there any solution for this? Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need it on Android and iOs, right? Because on other platforms seems to be implemented by default like you want it.
In any case, try this:

```
class ObscuringTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  ObscuringTextEditingController(String text) : super(text: text);

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({required BuildContext context, TextStyle? style, required bool withComposing}) {
    var displayValue = '•' * value.text.length;
    if (!value.composing.isValid || !withComposing) {
      return TextSpan(style: style, text: displayValue);
    }
    final TextStyle composingStyle = style?.merge(
          const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
        ) ??
        const TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.underline);
    return TextSpan(
      style: style,
      children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textBefore(displayValue)),
        TextSpan(
          style: composingStyle,
          text: value.composing.textInside(displayValue),
        ),
        TextSpan(text: value.composing.textAfter(displayValue)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Updated the original code from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32889#issuecomment-577465465)

Comment: yeah it works, but it seems my toggle hide and show button has no function since I customize the controller